# Уникальное множество array php

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

В БД есть 10 миллионов записей вида `user(int)` - `group(int)`.
Нужно положить все множество уникальных пользователей без повторений в таблицу `users`. Приведенный ниже код работает нереально долго и я так и не смог дождаться завершения его работы. Помогите, пожалуйста)

```
if ($_REQUEST['action'] === 'members_uniq') {
    $users_array = array();
    $startMemory = memory_get_usage();
    $res2 = array();
    $res3 = array();
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////---
     $res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM group2user");
     $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
     $total = $row[0]; // всего записей
     echo $total . '<br />';
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////---
    $per = 1000000;
    $cnttot = intval($total / $per);
    if (($total % $per) > 0) {
        $cnttot = $cnttot + 1;
    }
    echo $cnttot . '<br />';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $cnttot; $i++) {
    //for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $sqlzstr = "SELECT * FROM `group2user` GROUP BY `uid` LIMIT " . $i*$per . ", " . $per;
        echo $sqlzstr . '<br />';
        $sqlz = mysql_query($sqlzstr,$db)
                or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());

        $res1 = array();
        while ($rowz = mysql_fetch_array($sqlz, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            array_push($res1, $rowz['uid']);
            //echo $rowz['uid'] . '<br/>';
        }
        //var_dump($res1);
        //$array3 = array();
        echo count($res1) . '<br/>';
        $res1 = array_unique($res1);
        $res3 = array_merge($res1, $res3);
        $res3 = array_unique($res3);
        echo count($res3) . '<br/>';
        flush();
        unset($res1);
        unset($sqlz);
    }

    echo memory_get_usage() - $startMemory, ' bytes' . '<br/>';
    $per = 10000;

    $total = count($res3);
    $ttl = intval($total / $per);
    if (($total % $per) > 0) {
        $ttl = $ttl + 1;
    }
        echo '=========================================<br/>';
        echo $total . ' ' . $ttl . '<br/>';
        echo '=========================================<br/>';

     $endN = 1;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $ttl; $i++) {
        $sqlstr = "INSERT INTO `users` (`vkid`) VALUES ";
        $startN = $i*$per;
        if (($total - $endN) < $per) {
            $endN = $total;
            //echo 'good<br/>';
        } else {
            $endN = $startN + $per;
            //echo 'bad<br/>';
        };
        echo $startN . ' ' . $endN . '<br/>';
            for ($j = $startN; $j < $endN; $j++) {
                $sqlstr = $sqlstr . "('" . $res3[$j] . "'), ";
                //$sqlstr = $sqlstr . "('" . $j . "'), ";
            }
        $sqlstr = substr($sqlstr, 0, strlen($sqlstr)-2);
        $thesql = mysql_query($sqlstr, $db);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Делается одним SQL запросом

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`vkid`)
SELECT `uid` FROM `group2user`
 WHERE uid not in(SELECT `vkid` FROM `users`)
 GROUP BY `uid`
```